# Dynamically generated keys with Typescript and JSON

Tags: json, typescript

So I'm working on app with Typescript and React native. I have json file with some info on poker hands that I need to access from my app.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "22": [
    [
      0,
      20
    ]
  ],
  "32o": [
    [
      0,
      20
    ]
  ],
  "32s": [
    [
      0,
      20
    ]
  ],
  "33": [
    [
      0,
      20
    ]
  ],
```

I'm importing json data with

```
import * as pdata from './push.json';
```

Data can be accessed like this:

```
pdata['AA'][0][1]
```

However, if I try try to access json with dynamically created keys like this

```
currentHand = '32o';
console.log(pdata[currentHand][0][1]);
```

I get error saying "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '...' No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "22": number[][];...'.

Because of large amount of keys it is not really feasible to hardcode all different possibilities.
I've been searching for an answer but haven't found anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are declaring `currentHand` without `const`, Typescript expect that `currentHand` variable value can / will be changed, and it assume `currentHand` type to be a `string`

Now if you declare it with `const`:

```
import data from "./push.json";

const currentHand = "22";
console.log(data[currentHand][0][1]);
```

the type of `currentHand` will be `"22"` instead of `string`, and the error will no longer appear

> Because of large amount of keys it is not really feasible to hardcode all different possibilities. I've been searching for an answer but haven't found anything that works.

Try this

```
type DataKey = keyof typeof data; // DataKey type is "22" | 32o" | "32s" | ...

const currentHand: DataKey = "22";
// or
const currentHand = "22" as DataKey;

console.log(data[currentHand][0][1]);
```

Alternative way:

```
import data from "./push.json";

const dynamicData = <Data>(<any>data);

type Data = {
  [key: string]: [number[]];
  // or if value structure is always the same
  [key: string]: [[number, number]];
};


let currentHand = "22";
console.log(dynamicData[currentHand][0][1]);
```

Comment: I didn't get this to work either, but thanks anyways. I found solution using https://quicktype.io/ converter.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this using https://quicktype.io/.
With generated converter saved in Convert.ts, JSON data can be accessed like this:

```
import * as pdata from './push.json';
import { Convert } from './Convert'
    
const pushHands = Convert.toHands(JSON.stringify(pdata));
var ch = '42o';
console.log(pushHands['default'][ch][0][1]);
```